# How to create a command handler in DSharpPlus?

Tags: c#, .net-core, discord, dsharp+

I'm coming from Nextcord where we have cogs, but here I'm confused. What if I want one command per class? Do I have to register them all manually?

Here's what I'm doing now: I have a Bot class that has:

`var slash = discord.UseSlashCommands(); slash.RegisterCommands<DiscordCommand>();`

Then in my `DiscordCommand` class I have a few `Task`s with `\[SlashCommand\]` attributes.

Ideally I would want to make a new class for every command, and have that class inherit from a `BaseCommand` class that auto registers itself somehow. Is there a way to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a relatively easy way of doing this so that you don't need 100 lines of `slash.RegisterCommand<t>()` in your code. In this example we will assume you have the word "Command" in all class names that contain a command, and that all of your commands are in the namespace `Project.Commands`.

Instead of doing this:

```
var slash = discord.UseSlashCommands();
slash.RegisterCommands<FirstCommand>();
slash.RegisterCommands<SecondCommand>();
slash.RegisterCommands<ThirdCommand>();
```

We are going to loop through all the classes of the namespace `Project.Commands` and register these through the loop.

```
var slash = discord.UseSlashCommands();

var types = Assembly
    .GetExecutingAssembly()
    .GetTypes()
    .Where(t => t.Namespace.StartsWith("Project.Commands")) //Limit our namespace to Project.Commands
    .Where(s => s.Name.Contains("Command")); //Limit the types to those named with the word Command

foreach (var t in types)
{
    slash.RegisterCommands(t);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know you could do that!